# Tag synonym: fuel/petrol/gas

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Just noticed this bit of tag redundancy on a question.

[What are the benefits of premium (high octane) petrol?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-are-the-benefits-of-premium-high-octane-petrol)

That question has all of the following tags:  [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel)[gas](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas)[petrol](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petrol)

Could the powers that be consolidate this into one tag synonym?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. "Gas" and "petrol" are now synonyms of "Fuel".

Comment: @RobertCartaino - Wait, you lost me - "gas" and "petrol" are *not* synonyms of "fuel"?  In the context of this site, I thought they would be - or at worst be a subset of it?

Comment: N-O-W. "Now synonyms of fuel." My bad. Typo fixed. [status-completed]

Comment: Where I come diesel is also a fuel, but it isn't a synonym of petrol...

Comment: @Benjol - Ah, I wasn't aware of that.  Generally, "fuel" and "gas" are presumed to refer to unleaded around here also.  Though, technically, they *could* also refer to diesel.

Comment: @Iszi: [Fuel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel) is any material that stores energy that can later be extracted to perform mechanical work in a controlled manner. That includes Uranium, wood, even grass. Equating "fuel" with "unleaded petrol" is like equating "food" and "rice". Its not "technically they could", "fuel" simply is as broad term as "food". And "gas" is a very ambiguous term, for example over here in the context of cars it means a mixture of propane and butane. So please either remove those synonyms here, or also add synonyms for "rice" and "food" on Cooking.SE.

Comment: @miernik: This is a site for questions about cars.  I don't know of any cars that run on wood or uranium.  What kind of question would need the distinction between diesel and gasoline in the tag?  Sure they're different, but not different enough to have different tags.

Comment: @endolith: questions that are about something which is true for diesel fuel, but completely wrong in relation to unleaded petrol. For example additives, problems at low temperatures, etc. Do you want questions about winter additives for diesel fuel only appear to someone searching for "petrol" in tags, and break his car by adding that stuff to his tank?

Comment: @endolith: Just because you lack knowledge, does not mean phenomenon does not occur. So, there is such thing as [wood gas generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_gas_generator), where wood, charcoal etc. are sublimated into so-called wood gas which powers internal combustion engine. Just a sidenote.

Answer (score 4):

I think the tags should be [gasoline](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gasoline), [e85](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e85), [diesel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel), [electric](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric), [hydrogen](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrogen), [propane](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propane), [cng](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cng)

All of these are currently in use in the USA. There may be others as well. We don't need all of these now, but we do need to be more specific than [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel)

Comment: While there conceivably could be some questions regarding more than one (or all) of these fuel types, I agree that generally breaking it down like this would be a good idea.

Comment: Why do we need to be more specific than "fuel"?

Comment: @endolith because the systems are designed differently, E85 requires major changes to the fuel system, older cars cannot use >15 percent ethanol without modifications. Diesel and hydrogen work completely different than gasoline vehicles

Answer (score 3):

I think [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) should be an umbrella term, and used in tandem with more specific term for each particular case.