# Should the Diesel tag and Fuel tag be Synonyms?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

I was looking yesterday at a post. [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) was specified in the tags. The question was about [diesel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel), so I tried to add the tag, only to realize that [diesel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel) and [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) are set as synonyms. I clicked on the tag to see the related questions and started looking through them. I can tell you from the variety of questions, this *should not* be a tag synonym. There are a 128 questions which cover everything, but only a small portion of them are diesel related. Looking at them just now, there are three tags which flow into [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel), those being [gas](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas), [petrol](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petrol), [diesel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel). IMHO, this really should not be. If I were to have been setting this up, the following would hold true:

- [petrol](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petrol) and [gas](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas) would be synonyms, covering **petrol/gas engine** related items
- [diesel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel) would be its own tag, covering all things related to **diesel engine tech**
- [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) would be its own tag, covering all thing related to **fuel delivery**

To me these are very different things. I think a perusal through the questions will tell you there is way too many questions lumped into [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) which really doesn't make sense being there.

Just so you know I looked, there was [this question](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/tag-synonym-fuel-petrol-gas) posted here in the Meta where I think this all started. It was asked very early on in the Beta. I believe the outcome was a bit short sighted.

Comment: Agreed [See here](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/56/85) wasn't a mod then. Will fix when I get some time later today

Comment: @Larry ... I saw that you had written that. It looks as more of a knee jerk reaction by a brand new mod on a brand new beta. No big deal, but I think it causes some issues and makes the tag subject too large. Thanks!

Comment: I guess if I had read your entire question. I would have known that. Lol saw enough to know I already agreed and commented

Comment: @Larry How about also changing the fuel tag to fuel-delivery, so new posters won't get confused?

Comment: @Paul ... Not a bad idea, but if people would look at the tag properties in the first place, it wouldn't be an issue anyway. But, if the mods decided to go that way, I wouldn't have an issue. It would definitely be more descriptive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[diesel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diesel) is now on it's own.

[gasoline](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gasoline) is now on it's own.

[e85](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e85) is on it's own.

[cng](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cng) is on it's own.

[fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel) is now a synonym of [fuel-system](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel-system) since it already existed.

[gas-cap](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas-cap) is now a synonym of [fuel-cap](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel-cap)

[gas](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas) is now a synonym of [gasoline](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gasoline)

[injection](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection) is now a synonym of [fuel-injection](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel-injection)

Comment: Very nice! I think that will work splendidly! :D

Comment: Any changes to petrol?

Comment: @Freiheit There is no petrol tag. Use Gasoline